# Where can I find examples of high contrast combinations for websites?

Tags: website-design, color, contrast

I like the idea behind http://contrastrebellion.com/, and plan to implement that on my websites.

However, I'm a developer, not designer. I read a lot about the subject -where I must build the combination- but wonder where I can find great looking and proven combinations with dark & light backgrounds.

I try looking at some websites, but suspect the visual on them distort my ability to judge what exactly I'm looking for (I like it because is good contrast or because the site look good to me?).

Comment: Ironic that a website touting the virtues of usability would itself use a cluttered mess that requires javascript to be viewed "properly".

Comment: awwwards.com - there is a lot of website based on high cntrast

Comment: high contrast is no better than low contrast when it comes to readability. What is key is the right amount of contrast--not too little, not too much.

Answer (score 2):

At kuler you'll find a lot of [predefined color themes for high contrast](http://kuler.adobe.com/#themes/search?term=contrast). And [here](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/design/find-the-perfect-colors-for-your-website/) you'll find a huge collection of tools working with colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot tools for accessibility:

http://www.w3.org/WAI/RC/tools/complete

for contrast I use:

http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html

it's an easy to use online tool

Answer (score 0):

Base your contrast on colors that have big difference in Tint and Saturation (background vs text), here ther eis a resrouce that explain the different kind of contrast. Do not base on Hue contrast, they are not good for people with color blindness. http://www.colorsontheweb.com/colorcontrasts.asp

here there is another website that talk about contrast http://www.gomediazine.com/design-articles/technique-theory/rule-three-contrast-contrast-contrast/

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend picking your colors yourself** first, and then testing it on http://www.checkmycolours.com/.

But if you're looking for *color combinations* (which I think you are), it would be best to look at Adobe's Kuler over at http://kuler.adobe.com/#themes/search?term=tag%3Acontrast